# Passing encoded url as parameter javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

JS fiddle created at https://jsfiddle.net/ankitwasankar/sc50ecyf/ demonstrates, how the url sent as a parameter decode itself inside function. Is it the expected behaviour. Do I need to encode url passed as parameter again inside function. Currently when URL is opened with `window.location.href` it doesn't contain `%26` instead contains `&`. So on server, `HttpServletRequest.getParameterNames()` returns two parameters instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

What about split `%26` in-between, like:

```
<a href='javascript:print_me("https://www.google.co.in/search?query=a%2" + "6b=26")'>Click</a>
```

This prevents the auto-decoding, although it's a little bit hacky.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. Also double encoding the URL parameters solved the problem.